# Asking for the action of this 'for-loop'

Tags: c++, if-statement, for-loop, iterator

I could understand that `it`  is iterating the `buckets_` , but what is the action in this for loop? In my debugging,  `if (it->second)` is satisfied  `if (this->next()->putq(it->second) == -1)` is not satisfied. So does this for-loop could only judge if the GADGET fail or not?

```
 for (map_type_::iterator it = buckets_.begin(); it != buckets_.end(); it++) {
      if (it->second) {
      if (this->next()->putq(it->second) == -1) {
        it->second->release();
        GDEBUG("Failed to pass bucket down the chain\n");
        return GADGET_FAIL;
      }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your map most likely contains pointers. `if (it->second)` checks if the pointer is `NULL` or not, if not `NULL`, execution goes to next if statement (`if (this->next()->putq(it->second) == -1)`) most likely to "pass the bucket down the chain"...if this fails (returns -1), then `GADGET_FAIL` is returned as an erreor code.

It is possible that `putq` actually never returns -1, or, possibly only in very critical situations (system running out of memory for instance). So it's possible that the code inside the second `if` statement is (almost) impossible to reach.

So, the loop can judge if the GADGET "passing down the chain" failed or not. But it probably never fails.

That's all that can be said without more code of `putq` posted...